# How to extract regions from webcam images using setMouseCallback function

Tags: python, image, opencv, webcam

I am trying to write some code, where I want to save some images from the webcam on python using opencv and then I want to open each image, and on each image using a bounding box select a region of interest(ROI) that will be cropped out and save this cropped image in a new folder. For this, I am using the cv2.setMouseCallback and drawing a rectangle on each image. My code works, but the cropped images that are stored are very strange.

```
import cv2
  
# Opens the inbuilt camera of laptop to capture video.
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
i = 0
training_images = []

def draw_bounding_box(click, x, y, flag_param, parameters):
    global x_pt, y_pt, drawing, top_left_point, bottom_right_point, image
    
    if click == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing = True
        print("drawing="+str(drawing))
        x_pt, y_pt = x, y
        print("x_pt="+str(x_pt))

    elif click == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing:
            top_left_point, bottom_right_point = (x_pt,y_pt), (x,y)
            image[y_pt:y, x_pt:x] = 255 - image[y_pt:y, x_pt:x]
            cv2.rectangle(image, top_left_point, bottom_right_point, (0,255,0), 2)
    
    elif click == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        drawing = False
        top_left_point, bottom_right_point = (x_pt,y_pt), (x,y)
        copy[y_pt:y, x_pt:x] = 255 - copy[y_pt:y, x_pt:x]
        cv2.rectangle(image, top_left_point, bottom_right_point, (0,255,0), 2)
        bounding_box = (x_pt, y_pt, x-x_pt, y-y_pt)

        cropped_im = image[y_pt:y,x_pt:x]
        training_images.append(cropped_im)
        if len(cropped_im)>0:
            cv2.imshow("cropped",cropped_im)
            cv2.imwrite('C:/Downloads/testingPictures/Frame'+str(i)+'.jpg',cropped_im)
            cv2.waitKey(3000)
        else:
            print("could not save")
        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    drawing = False
    while(cap.isOpened() and i<10):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
          
        # This condition prevents from infinite looping 
        # incase video ends.
        if ret == False:
            break
          
        # Save Frame by Frame into disk using imwrite method
        cv2.imwrite('C:/Downloads/testingPictures/Frame'+str(i)+'.jpg', frame)
        i += 1
    print(i)
    
    while(i>=1):
        image = cv2.imread('C:/Users/shrut/Downloads/testingPictures/Frame'+str(i-1)+'.jpg')
        copy = image.copy()
        i = i-1
        s = len(training_images)
        cv2.namedWindow('Frame')
        cv2.imshow('Frame', copy)
        cv2.setMouseCallback('Frame', draw_bounding_box)
        s_curr = len(training_images)
        k = cv2.waitKey(5000) & 0xFF
        if k == 27:
            break
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        print(i)
        
        
    print(len(training_images))
```

[This is what the saved "cropped images" look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHEAE.jpg)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUrEs.jpg)
It looks like multiple bounding boxes superposed on the image. How can I avoid this and get the area from the image instead?

Comment: It's because your callback is processing `cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE` so it draws a rectangle for every intermediate mouse position between mouse depress and release.

Comment: Ok, I think I need that since for each image I would like to draw a rectangle (my bounding box) to select and crop out a region in the image. How do I change the code so that this is done for each image I read?

Comment: Just draw on, and display a **copy**. Draw final lines on another **copy** and save that.